# What is the correct way to use the definitelyscala node facade in scala-js?

Tags: node.js, scala.js

There's something fundamental I'm missing about using facades with scala-js.

Obviously, this is wrong:

```
package foo.webapp
import com.definitelyscala.node.util.Util
import scala.scalajs.js.JSApp

object FooApp extends JSApp {
    override def main(): Unit = {
        Util.debug("debug")
    }
}
```

because I get:

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Weird, if you look at the signature of `Util` in its source, it's defined in such a way that it expects a `util` global variable to exist in JS. But it will not exist, you need to do a `require('util')` in JS to get a reference to util. Scala.js alternative to that is @JSImport, but I'm not quite sure how the authors of those bindings intended you to use them. See https://github.com/scalajs-io/nodejs/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/scalajs/nodejs/util/Util.scala#L226 for an implementation of the same Util in a different library, that's how I would have expected it to work.

Comment: @nikita Thanks, I gathered I was supposed to have a `util` global variable, just don't know the right way to get one.

Comment: You're not supposed to. `util` is a module. IMO the facade you're trying to use is just plain wrong. You should use https://github.com/scalajs-io/nodejs which is much better maintained.

Comment: @sjrd Thanks!  I was starting to think that.